# Is there a Python module that can fit a generalized linear mixed model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, python

I've built a mixed model in R using `glmer` from the `lme4` package. I now wish to incorporate this model in Python. My R code is of the form

> fit_model <- glmer(A * B * C + (1|x) + (1|y) + (1|z),  data=data, family=binomial, nAGQ=0).

Can this model fitting be replicated in Python? I've come across the `statsmodels` module, but it is not clear to me if `statsmodels` will be able to fit the same model that `glmer` was able to.

Comment: why not just use an R kernel in python, like rpy2?

Comment: Because that compounds the difficulty of refactoring the model for most people. Integration is often buggy, hard to maintain, etc etc

Comment: statsmodels doesn't have mixed effects GLM yet. There was a Google Summer of Code project for it this year, and it might become available in half a year to a year.

Comment: @user333700 what's the difference between the mixed effects model in statsmodels 0.6.0 and the one OP is asking about?

Comment: @max statsmodels still has only the linear mixed effects model. The OP asks for binomial, i.e. Logit.